# compare if two columns of a file is identiical in linux

Tags: linux

I would like to compare if two columns (mid) in a file is identical to each other. I am not sure of how to do it...Since the original file that I am working one is rather huge (in Gb)

file 1 (column1 and column 4 - to check if they are identical)

```
mid A1  A2  mid A3  A4  A5  A6
18  we  gf  18  32  23  45  89
19  ew  fg  19  33  24  46  90
21  ew  fg  21  35  26  48  92
```

Thanks
M

Comment: What have you tried? I think you could cut out the columns you want and diff them fairly easily. Is it because the files are too large? Is that a problem for you to use that much disk space?

Comment: Can you show a line with different values in the columns and the expected output?

Comment: I am new to linux and got no clue of where to start

Comment: It's hard to know what you want the output to be, but I would start with awk/gawk to get the columns, and compare them, then you could either print out which lines are different, or keep a tally, or...

Comment: also in the original file - I believe the columns are identical - BUT want to double check it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you just need to find the different row, `awk` will do,

```
awk '$1!=$4{print $1,$4}' data
```

You can check using `diff` and `awk` for advance difference.

```
diff <(awk '{print $1}' data) <(awk '{print $4}' data)
```

The status code (`$?`)of this command will tell if they are same (zero) or different (non-zero).

You can use that in base expression like this too,

```
if diff <(awk '{print $1}' data) <(awk '{print $4}' data) >& /dev/null;
then 
    echo same; 
else 
    echo different; 
fi
```

Comment: thanks man.. it worked like charm... can you explain what >& /dev/null;   does in this equation.. I am new and would like to learn

Comment: `>& /dev/null` redirects any output to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
awk '{ if ($1 == $4) { print "same"; } else { print "different"; } }' < foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Completing a litle bit the [Shiplu Mokaddim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376535/shiplu-mokaddim) answer, if you have another delimiter, for example in a csv file, you can use:

```
awk -F; '$1!=$4{print $1,$4}' data.csv | sed -r 's/ /;/g'
```

In this sample, the delimiter is a ";". The sed command in the end is to replace again the delimiter to the original one. Be sure that you don´t have another space in you answer, i.e. and date time.

Answer (score -1):

Question: Compare two columns value in the same file.

Answer:

```
cut -d, -f1 a.txt > b.txt ; cut -d, -f3 a.txt > c.txt ; cmp b.txt c.txt && echo "Column values are same"; rm -rf b.txt c.txt
```